# randomly displaying sprite image

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hi currently my game is loading fl_gfood.png or fl_bfood.png from the fl_food.plist. That works fine but now I have 17 bad food items .png and 17 good food items .png. My question is how do I randomly display one of the 17 items from each group? Can I just do a wildcard for the sprite png file name? See code comment below. Also a suggestion was made that I could possibly load the .plist file names into an array and randomly pick a name, how would that be done.

```
@implementation Food

+ (void)loadAssets {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [[FLSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[AssetHelper getDeviceSpecificFileNameFor:@"fl_food.plist"]];
    });

}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.size                   = CGSizeMake(16 * __HIGHRES_SCALE, 16 * __HIGHRES_SCALE);
        self.offset                 = CGPointMake(8 * __HIGHRES_SCALE, 8 * __HIGHRES_SCALE);
        self.removeAfterCollision   = YES;
        self.collideable            = NO;
        self.score                  = 10;
    }
    return self;
}

- (FLSprite *)sprite {
    if(_sprite == nil) {

        if(self.score < 10) {
            _sprite = [FLSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"fl_gfood.png"]; // fl_gfood_*.png ... Can I do something like this?
        } else {
            _sprite = [FLSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"fl_bfood.png"];
        }
    }
    return _sprite;
}
```

Comment: Just make a function that returns the name of the sprite randomly or based on any conditions that you want.

Comment: @setrio can you show and example on how to do that?

Comment: check arc4random, build an array with all the images names and generate the idx for that array using arc4random. Just return the content of the array at the given idx

Comment: Spent 6hrs on this and no luck, can someone assist me with a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use arc4random() and stringByAppendingString

```
- (FLSprite *)sprite {
    if(_sprite == nil) {
        NSString *disFood;

        disFood = (self.score < 10) ? @"fl_gfood" : @"fl_bfood";

        //random # between 1 - 10
        int randNum  = (arc4random() % 10)+1;

        NSString *formattedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%i.png",randNum];

        disFood = [disFood stringByAppendingString:formattedName];

        _sprite = [FLSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:disFood]; 

        NSLog(disFood);//Logging disFood String;
    }
    return _sprite;
}
```

Comment: My app is hanging with no error. How about this, I have another plist at has 34 filenames and I just want one of the 34 files to randomly load into the frameName. I think this would be more simple?

Comment: sorry I forgot to set disFood to the appended string like so:

Comment: `disFood = [disFood stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%i.png",randNum]];
        _sprite = [FLSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:disFood];`

Comment: I edited it in the above response as well.(Tested and working this time)